# How to Install OG Whatsapp in windows phone

Tags: windows-10-mobile, whatsapp

How to install the OG Whatsapp in windows 10 OS for windows phone.How to use 2 numbers in whatsapp in windows Phone.Please can any one help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dual whatsapp in W10M?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/14521/how-to-use-dual-whatsapp-in-w10m)

Answer (score -1):

The only think I can think of if you wanna use two different whatsapp numbers is having the original Whatsapp application and the beta one. You might be able to log with differents account on each app (but I'm not even sure that'll work)

Found a little link to explain how to enroll to the beta
https://www.techmesto.com/enroll-whatsapp-private-beta-windows-phone/

Comment: Does it works really