# How to use dual whatsapp in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, whatsapp, nokia-lumia-535

I have migrated from android platform and there I was using multiple whatsapp accounts on a single phone using third party applications but since windows is a closed platform, can I use a separate whatsapp account for each SIM on my Lumia 535 DS running on windows 10 mobile? I have asked the same question for WP8.1 [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/how-to-use-dual-whatsapp-in-lumia-535-running-wp8-1) and the activities on this question make me to think that its not possible on WP8.1. Now I have updated on W10M and still need the answer of the question if it is possible for W10M. So is it possible on W10M? My phone's L535 running W10 build 14393.693.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dual whatsapp by using the beta version and normal version. Here are the store links

1. [Microsoft Store - Whatsapp Beta](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/whatsapp-beta/9wzdncrdfwbt)
2. [Microsoft Store - Whatsapp](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/whatsapp/9wzdncrdfwbs)

Comment: Awsome man! It worked for WP8.1 as well! Plz have a look on linked question as well.